# Python program that will loop through the array and place all the odd numbered pupils in a new array called ‘group1’

Tags: python, arrays, list

A program to store an array of 20 pupils.  sort them into two groups for a group activity. Write a Python program that will loop through the array and place all the odd numbered pupils in a new array called `group1` and the even numbered students in a new array called `group2` need help with how to do this

```
pupil=  []
numpupil = input('Number of Pupils: ')
for #need help with the for loop and continuing onward from this
    pupil[index] = input("Pupil  " + str(pupil))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
group1,group2 = zip(*[iter(list_of_pupils)]*2)
```

of course that may not be quite what your teacher is expecting .... and best of  luck with the test later